# If a linear operator between two normed linear spaces is continuous at one point, then it is continuous at all points.

Tags: linear-algebra, continuity, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let $f : \langle V_1, \|\cdot\|_1\rangle \to \langle V_2, \|\cdot\|_2\rangle$ be linear.  Then if $f$ is continuous at some $v \in V_1$, then it is continuous on all of $V_1$.  Without appealing to boundedness, because that's an equivalent condition that I'm proving in my next problem.

My attempt. Proof:

We want to show that for all $v \in V, \ \ v_n \to v \implies f(v_n) \to f(v)$. Assume we know that $f$ is continuous at $0$. then $v_n \to v \implies v_n - v \to 0  \implies f(v_n - v) \to 0 \implies f(v_n) \to f(v)$ by linearity.

But I'm having trouble proving that given any single point of continuity $v \in V$, $f$ is also continuous at $0$.

My best guess is: $v_n \to v $ and $ w_n \to 0 \implies v_n - w_n \to v \implies f(v_n - w_n) = f(v_n) - f(w_n) \to f(v) \implies f(w_n) \to 0$

Comment: Say $f$ is continuous at $p$. If $v_n\to v$ then $p+(v_n-v)\to p$.

Comment: I found that hint slightly cryptic; expounding a little more, $A(p+(v_n-v))=Ap+A(v_n-v) \to Ap$. Now what?

Comment: I think I solved it, see the last paragraph above.

Comment: Note the assertion comes essentially from the fact that a group homomorphism between topological groups is continuous if and only if it is continuous at $0$.